# Associations between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Thank you for visiting. I'm currently building a blogging app which will have 3 models. User, Article and Comments that will go into comments. I hope someone can help explain to me where I'm going wrong and how I can associated models better. Current error I get is undefined method `users' in Articles#new controller.

My current code is:

*Schema*

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end

 create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
 end

 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.text     "about_me"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
 end
```

*Models*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_secure_password
 has_many :articles
 has_many :comments
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :comments

 validates :user_id, presence: true
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :post
 belongs_to :user
end
```

*Controller*

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def index
  @articles = Article.all
 end

 def new
  @article = Article.new
 end

 def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @article = @user.articles.create(article_params)
  if @article.save
    redirect_to articles_path
  else
    redirect_to new_article_path
  end
 end

 def show
 end

 def edit
 end

 def update
  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to :back
  else

  end
 end

 def destroy
  if @article.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroy the article"
    redirect_to @article
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Couldnt delete article"
    redirect_to :back
  end
 end

 private

 def find_article
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
 end

 def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
 end
end
```

*View*

```
<%= form_for(@article, @article.users.build) do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :title %>
 <%= f.text_field :title %>
 <%= f.label :body %>
 <%= f.text_field :body %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

*Routes*

```
root 'users#index'

resources :users
resources :articles do
 resources :comments
end
```

If there is something else I might be missing in order to help explain what I'm doing wrong and how to improve/understanding association and building/creating. Please let me know and I'll add the additional information.

For everyone who teaches me/helps me, seriously thank you.

Comment: What is exactly that you are having trouble with? I can't really see a question or problem statement in there.

Comment: @max I can't seem to build(understand) an association between User and Article. I get undefined method 'users' in the form. Let me update my question. Sorry.

Comment: What is the role of the view? Create a new article or comments on an article?

Comment: @Iceman The view is in article/new. It suppose to create a new article and associate itself with a user.id. This way it can be shown later a list of articles the user created in their profile page.

Comment: You associate it with a user in the controller, the form should just be `form_for @article`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should be

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
```

Then in the controller

```
def create
  @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to articles_path
  else
    redirect_to new_article_path
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm going to have to create a session first it seems since I'm getting couldn't find User with ID now.

Comment: If you want to assign it to the currently signed in user yes. Aren't you using some sort of authentication system already?

Comment: Thank you. I know I messed up not having a login/session included for my user before trying to connect both Article and User together. This was perfect and it'll help me in the future. Hope you have a great day.

Comment: Actually a final question. If I want to list all articles the user has. How would I go about that?<% current_user.articles.each do |article| %> ?

Comment: Yes, that would work